# How to display null values for a field if some other field has values in Oracle

Tags: oracle10g

We have requirement wherein we need to display the sum of line cost for all the labor, material, service, tools associated to work order in Maximo. I have written the query however the sum of material line cost is getting doubled of there are more than one service line cost.
For example

> wonum  - 1234
>
> material line cost - 10
>
> service line cost - 5 and 6 ( 2 service lines)
>
> total material line cost - 20
>
> total service line cost - 11

The total for material line cost is wrong. I have used the below query, please let me know how to fix it

```
select a.wonum,a.description,a.location,a.crewid,a.worktype,a.wopriority,a.supervisor,a.actstart,a.siteid,sum(d.linecost) as totalmaterialcost,
sum(b.loadedcost)as totalservicecost
from workorder a
 left outer join matusetrans d
on  a.wonum=d.refwo and a.siteid=d.siteid
left outer join servrectrans b
 on  a.wonum=b.refwo and a.siteid=b.siteid
where a.wonum='1234' and a.siteid='ABC'
 group by a.wonum,a.description,a.location,a.crewid,a.worktype,a.wopriority,a.supervisor,a.actstart,a.siteid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WORKORDER table will calculate these values for you already. Are the following fields not providing the data you need?

ACTINTLABCOST
ACTLABCOST
ACTMATCOST
ACTOUTLABCOST
ACTSERVCOST
ACTTOOLCOST

ESTATAPPRINTLABCOST
ESTATAPPRLABCOST
ESTATAPPRMATCOST
ESTATAPPROUTLABCOST
ESTATAPPRSERVCOST
ESTATAPPRTOOLCOST
ESTINTLABCOST
ESTLABCOST
ESTMATCOST
ESTOUTLABCOST
ESTSERVCOST
ESTTOOLCOST

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the joins are all at the top level of your statement. This leads to multiple lines/records per *workorder*.

One solution would be to calculate the sum of *matusetrans* and *servrectrans* in two seperate sub-select-statements.

Example:

```
select a.wonum, 
    b.sum as totalservicecost, 
    d.sum as totalmaterialcost
from workorder a
left join (
    select sum(b.loadedcost) as sum, b.siteid, b.refwo 
    from servrectrans b 
    group by b.siteid, b.refwo
) b on a.wonum = b.refwo and a.siteid = b.siteid
left join (
    -- second sum-select goes here
) d on -- second join condition goes here
```

As a second approach check the workorder-table for columns already containing this data (eventually there is some de-normalization to boost performance).

Comment: Hi Dani , It works however the result takes a longer time to come so this query is affecting performance. Please note that this query is used in a report and the report has 4 input parameters already.

Comment: check for colums containing pre-aggregated data.